# Finish activity before it starts?

Tags: android

I have registered my activity to handle the ACTION_DIAL intent but in certain cases I want to basically ignore the intent.  In onCreate, I'm checking SharedPreferences for a bool that means user has access to dial, if not then I call finish() and then return;  But this still shows a window flashing open and then closed, how can I avoid that?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean hasDialer = prefs.getBoolean(Preferences.HAS_DIALER, false);

    // Check if ACTION_DIAL intent was launched to bring user into the app
    String number = getIntent().getDataString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(number))
    {
        if (hasDialer)
        {
            launchDialer = true;
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could register the `ACTION_DIAL` in a broadcast receiver (directly in the manifest) or in a service (now this depends on what else are you planning to do) and have the same logic in there. You can start activities from there if you need to.

Comment: I just need to launch an activity with the data from the intent, so I'll use a BroadcastReceiver.  Thanks!

Comment: I made this change but now the user doesn't see my app listed in the choices when they click on a phone number, I guess it needs to be an activity for that?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be ... but you didn't mentioned that in your question. Anyway, in that case it's a bad UI practice to not show some UI from your application. Since you put an activity to handle `ACTION_DIAL` and then it immediately pops off you leave the user confused.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll pop up a message and close the activity in that case.  Thanks for the help.